# How to prevent an image in the email-signature to become an attachment?

Tags: outlook, vml

The situation:
- Outlook is set to "Read all Email in plain text"
- The user has not only exchange, but some other Email-provider
Then a received email with a logo in the signature becomes an email with the logo as attachment.

To prevent this, I created my logo in vml and inserted it in the signature.

But: 
Outlook converts the vml in a png - and I have again attachments!

Question:
Is the a way of cute vml programming to prevent my vml to become a png?

This is what I inserted:

```html
<!--[if gte vml 1]>
<v:group id="Page01"; style="position:relative; width:21.5mm; height:28mm;"
  coordsize="612,792"  coordorigin="0,0">
<v:shape style="position:absolute;width:612;height:792;" coordsize="612,792"
 fillcolor="#000000" stroked="f" path="
m 275,0 l 247,1 220,6 193,12 168,22 144,33 121,47 100,63 81,81 63,100 47,121 33,144 22,168 12,193 6,220 1,247 0,275 1,303 6,330 12,357 22,382 33,406 47,429 63,450 81,470 100,487 121,503 144,517 168,528 193,538 220,544 247,549 275,550 303,549 330,544 357,538 382,528 406,517 429,503 450,487 470,470 487,450 503,429 517,406 528,382 538,357 544,330 549,303 550,275 549,247 544,220 538,193 528,168 517,144 503,121 487,100 470,81 450,63 429,47 406,33 382,22 357,12 330,6 303,1 275,0xe">
</v:shape>
...
</v:group>

<![endif]-->
```

Comment: and .. I also tried an external linked image. But then the user will see "Pleas cklich to show pictures".

Comment: There is nothing you can do - unless you run code on the machine where the message is turned from HTML to the text format.